# How do I apply a painted texture to a mesh?

Tags: texturing

Blender version: 2.79b

I've texture painted a rabbit, using the clone-from-image method. I'm using a 1024x1024 canvas and an image of the same dimensions from which to clone.

The texturing looks fine when I look at it in Texture Paint mode,
[image: looks good here]
but when I look at it in rendered mode, there are weird distortions.
[image: how it looks in rendered mode]
The head is completely black and the eyes are on the belly and not on the head.

Using the Mapping node in the Node Editor, it goes completely black regardless of whether I use a generated or uv coordinate or any of the other options. When I use an image texture node without a vector argument, as in the screenshot with the checkmark, I get the aforementioned distortions.

Some of the black parts of the rabbit that are supposed to be colored are right where I created seams, but not all of them are. I've indicated the seams with blue circles, but not all of the seams are in the screenshot. The black parts on the ears and the bottoms of the feet are right where I created seams, but not the neck.

Here is the youtube video that I tried to learn how to do this with:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=64hsNokseZM

The spikes are due to an improperly applied particle system (I was giving my lagomorph some whiskers). I don't believe that they are related to this issue.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: maybe pack the image texture and share the file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Mesh can have several UV maps however by default only one will be used for rendering unless explicitly set up in the Node editor. If you painted the texture then UV map was used hence you want it to be used. So check what map is set to be rendered or plug desired one in the node editor (Shift+A > Input> UV map)

Comment: That solved it! Now I just need to mark this question as answered...

Comment: Do only moderators mark these questions as answered?